# Visual Studio Debugger displays wrong values for native types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, native

I am writing a program in managed C++ and native C++ using Visual Studio 2008 (Version 9.0.30729.1 SP) and .NET 3.5.
When debugging, Visual Studio displays obviously wrong values for types like size_t and pointers that are native.
Using messageboxes, I can verify that the actual values are correct though.
Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Here is a screenshot to clarify what I mean:

[image: Visual Studio displaying wrong values for native types]

Comment: Are you running the debug version of the program? I seem to remember there being "funnies" with reading variables when running the release version. It is some time ago no though, so I could be mis-remembering.

Comment: Yes, I am running the debug version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that switching the `Common Language Runtime Support` under `Configuration Properties` from `Pure MSIL Common Language Runtime Support (/clr:pure)` to `Common Language Runtime Support (
/clr)` did the trick. I can now view native objects just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [KB957912](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912) (Updates for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 debugging and breakpoints), it may help you.

Comment: I installed the Update, but it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the type of g_pGame, but it is possible to write extensions for Visual Studio so you can view the values of your custom types. Although that feature is mainly targeted for other use, like you have your own String container and you know it's internal details and you want to simply see the string value in it. So normally it is not for working around misbehavior. Also, writing such extension needs effort, and it won't help the problem with other types. But I want to let you know.