# MS Visual C++ 2010 Express keeps running old code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express. When I want to run a program, it only works the first time. With this I mean that after I run it for the first time, and change my code all together and then try to run it again, it just keeps running my old code. How can I prevent this from happening?

p.s. - I use 'Build Solution' after I'm done with my new code but it still happens

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but have you tried "Rebuild solution"? It's Ctrl-Alt-F7 in the keyboard shorcuts. It will rebuild as if it's the first time.

Comment: Long shot, but I'll just say it: is your clock somehow tempered? Sounds like your system does not know which objects are out-dated on a rebuild...

Answer (score 0):

Figure I might as well make it an actual answer:

If you clock is tempered (@anhoppe) then that could cause a problem, and it could also be something to do with your debugging cache. I recommend research in that. One place to look could be this: [How to reset the VisualStudio (VS2010, VS2012) debugger cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721032/how-to-reset-the-vs2010-debugger-cache)

And finally, seemingly obvious, try the "Rebuild Solution" (@Kevin) if you haven't already.