# QtCreator 3 with CDB shows wrong values in debugger

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I use QtCreator 3 with Qt 5.2 and the VS2012 compiler, CDB debugger from windows debugging tools.
While debugging a program (debug build), I noticed that the values shown in the debugger are sometimes wrong. I can reproduce the problem on the following minimal example:

```
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

struct SubPart
{
    unsigned short v1, v2, v3;
};

struct Part
{
    void appendSubPart(unsigned short v1, unsigned short v2, unsigned short v3)
    {
        SubPart newSubPart;
        newSubPart.v1 = v1;
        newSubPart.v2 = v2;
        newSubPart.v3 = v3;
        subParts_ << newSubPart;
    }

    QList<SubPart> subParts_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Part part;
    part.appendSubPart(1, 2, 3);
    part.appendSubPart(3, 4, 5);

    SubPart &ref(part.subParts_[0]);

    // Debug print the content of part.subParts_
    for ( auto &i : part.subParts_ ) {
        qDebug() << i.v1 << i.v2 << i.v3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output is (as expected):

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
```

But debugger shows:

[image: Debugger screenshot]

The debugger view of the QList `part.subParts_` is garbage. The reference `ref` to an element in the list fine.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Exactly where is your breakpoint? At the line of the comment?

Comment: The breakpoint for the screenshot was on the line `return 0;`, but it shows the same if the breakpoint is on the line `for ( auto &i : part.subParts_ ) {`

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250589/visual-studio-debugger-displays-wrong-values-for-native-types

Comment: Also, it's C#, but related to VS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126642/visual-studio-showing-wrong-values-while-debugging

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think the issues in the links are unrelated (it's mostly about CLR stuff). Here it looks like the problem is in the data formatter for the Qt data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Qt Creator to version 3.0.1 and Qt to version 5.2.1 solved the problem. The debug view of the QList shows the correct values.